# How to detect the touch sound of an device through code

Tags: android

Actually i want to know, how can i detect touch sound of an device through code, I mean to say i want to detect whether the touch sound is enable or disable in the device.

I Google this, but not able to find the correct solution for that. If anyone knows, help me to solve this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED` setting in [Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED).

I.e. something like this:

```
boolean clickSoundsEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED, 0) != 0;
```

Comment: Yep your answer is correct but need some modification, we have to use it like that boolean clickSoundsEnabled = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED, 0) != 0;

Answer (score 0):

Please try to check this field: `Setting.system.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED`